# Diary Entry - A Tale of Torture and Abuse

Tags: riddle

The following is a chilling entry from someone's diary:

> I'm not sure what day it is anymore.  My siblings and I had lost track of how long we'd been stuck in this dark and cramped prison cell.  It was hard to breathe and we had almost lost all hope.
>
> Then something happened earlier tonight.  We heard voices and some people outside were obviously trying to break us out.  It sounded like something was blocking the door, but they removed that and then they pulled the door open pretty quickly.  They got all of us out of there, and they seemed happy to help us.  We were so grateful that these strangers showed up and saved us.  We thought we were finally free.
>
> But then the strangers threw two of my brothers back into the cell for some reason.  We soon realized that they weren't rescuing us.  They were very evil people with sinister plans.  We couldn't have imagined the horror we were about to endure.  I wish I had died in the prison cell instead of having to go through what we went through.
>
> It's really hard for me to write this, but I have to force myself to finish this.  People have to know the disgusting things that were done to us.  The first thing they did was gather up me and my siblings.  Then one of them proceeded to spank all of us.  It was very painful, and he did it with incredible efficiency.  He was obviously very skilled at this type of torture.  Then he did it to us a few more times.  It was horrible - I'd never heard of or experienced anything like that before.
>
> When he finally stopped, he said something that made us think they were going to knife all of us.  I'd never been so frightened in my life.  But apparently it was just a scare tactic, because they didn't actually get a knife or anything.
>
> Then he started throwing many of us across the floor, one by one.  The other torturers dragged our bodies around, and we got carpet burn on our faces.  Unfortunately, the worst was yet to come.
>
> Those of us who had been thrown across the floor were then split up into groups, and a different tormentor abused each group of us.  My tormenter grabbed me and the others, and he started ogling and fondling us.  He was grinning when he was looking at me, and I felt nauseous.  It was truly awful - the sicko wouldn't keep his hands off of us.  My siblings in the other groups said they suffered the same kind of molesting from their tormentors.
>
> Then my tormentor apparently got tired of a few of us, because he sent some of us back to the other guy, who sent over a few of my other siblings in return.  Then he started ogling and fondling them too.  Finally he yelled something and slammed all of our bodies onto the floor.  It hurt so much and I have no idea what we did to deserve that punishment.
>
> This abuse was repeated several more times during the night.  Each time they'd gather all of us up, spank us, throw us and drag us across the floor, split us up into groups, and then molest us.  Finally when they were done, they shoved all of us back into the prison cell.  I also heard one of the tormentors say that he was looking forward to abusing us again tomorrow.  The thought of going through this pain and torture again is unbearable.  I am thinking about killing myself now.

**Questions:**

Who is the author, and who are his/her siblings?

Who are the two siblings who were put back into the prison cell at the beginning?

What happened exactly during each of these forms of torture/abuse:

- spanking
- words that made them think they would be knifed
- throwing their bodies across the floor and then dragging them around
- ogling and fondling
- sending some of the siblings back and getting others in return
- yelling and slamming their bodies onto the floor

Comment: I read the part about spanking and the knife and I thought, "oh, it could be a baby being born!" (Knife alluding to cutting the umbilical cord.) Then I got to the part about throwing them on the floor, dragging them around, and fondling them, and now I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The author is

> a playing card. The king of hearts in particular. (Thanks dperry for figuring out the specific card.) The king of hearts is also called the "suicide king" and the players also grin while looking at it, meaning it could be a high value card, like a king.

The two siblings who were put back into the prison cell at the beginning are

> the two Joker cards, which are not relevant to the game of 5 Card Draw. (Thank you Bailey M for figuring out the game.)

Spanking is

> shuffling.

The fear of knifing could be

> the dealer asking another player to make the cut, an act in card playing where the other player divides the pile of cards into two by taking away and separating a certain number of the cards, with the dealer starting distribution from the pile left with him.

Throwing bodies around and dragging is

> the distribution and collection of cards by the players.

Ogling and fondling is

> a player looking at his card and fidgeting with it while thinking and strategizing.

Sending some of the siblings back and getting others in return is

> players exchanging their cards to improve their hands.

Yelling and slamming their bodies onto the floor is

> Slamming the cards down when the loser realizes he's been beat (by a better hand) or bluffed out (by a weaker hand).

Comment: What about the comment about stabbing/knifing?

Comment: "Sending some back and getting others in return" is probably a reference to 5-Card Draw. I expect that "slamming the bodies to the floor" is revealing your hand, in that case.

Comment: @BaileyM Yes about the game.  Also, the yelling/slamming is more likely someone who was pissed to have lost.  :)

Comment: Who is the author specifically? There are a couple clues for that.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Is it an Ace? "He was grinning when he was looking at me, and I felt nauseous." Because the Ace has the highest value in the pack.

Comment: That's one clue, but it's not an Ace.  Another clue should narrow it down.

Comment: I would venture to guess that the author is the Queen of Spades and the game they are playing is Hearts.  The parts that stuck out to me for this were that the players sorted their hands: "Those of us who had been thrown across the floor were then split up into groups" which is a common tactic to sort by suit and then the author specifically mentioned    their "tormentor" as smiling when the tormentor saw the author.  The Queen of Spades is a quite powerful card in Hearts and could be why the tormentor is smiling.  I didn't make a separate answer because this should just add to the current one

Comment: @Ryan It's not the Queen of Spades

Comment: @pacoverflow: Not entirely sure, but I think it might be the 4 of diamonds. "It's really hard for me to write this, but I have to force myself to finish this." It's really hard could mean diamond, and force is a wordplay on "fours"?

Comment: I think the author is the "suicide king", the last line being "I am thinking about killing myself now"

Comment: @dperry: I think that might be it.

Comment: @dperry You are correct